# Splitting Python string

Tags: python

Split the string into pairs of two characters. If the string contains an odd number of characters, then the missing second character of the final pair should be replaced with an underscore ('_').

Input: A string.

Output: An iterable of strings.

Example:

```
split_pairs('abcd') == ['ab', 'cd']
split_pairs('abc') == ['ab', 'c_']
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You can use slicing to get two halves. `input_string[:len(input_string)//2)]` should get you one half and `input_string[len(input_string)//2:]` should get you another half. Now you can do the rest

Comment: @RishiDev I wonder how it will help for the input `abcdefgh`...

Comment: `[(string+'_')[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2)]`

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
import re

def solution(s):
    return re.findall(".{2}", s + "_")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import textwrap

def split_pairs(input):
    # Use textwrap to split the input into chunks of two characters
    split = textwrap.wrap(input, 2)

    # In your example I see you want a "_" if string is odd length
    # Check the length of the last chunk, and if it is 1, add a "_"

    if len(split[-1]) == 1:
        split[-1] += "_"
    return split


print(split_pairs('abcd'))
print(split_pairs('abc'))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

```
st = input('Input a string:')
arr = [] 
if len(st)%2==0:
    for i in range(0,len(st)-1,2):
        arr.append(st[i]+st[i+1])
else:
    st +='_'
    for i in range(0,len(st)-1,2):
        arr.append(st[i]+st[i+1])
print(arr)
```

also if you want to enter a long text and strip white spaces after it try st = st.replace(' ','') after the input:

```
st = input('Input a string:')
st = st.replace(' ','')
arr = [] 
if len(st)%2==0:
    for i in range(0,len(st)-1,2):
        arr.append(st[i]+st[i+1])
else:
    st +='_'
    for i in range(0,len(st)-1,2):
        arr.append(st[i]+st[i+1])
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this short function without imports:

```
def split_pairs(inp):
    pairs = [inp[2*i:2*i+2] for i in range(len(inp) // 2)]
    if len(inp) % 2 == 1:
        pairs.append(f'{inp[-1]}_')
    return pairs
```